# Reading an HTTP stream in python

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to read the output of the Twitter streaming API and I'm having some trouble. Here is my code so far:

```
from urllib2 import *
import StringIO

password_mgr = HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, 'myusername', 'mypassword')
h = HTTPBasicAuthHandler(password_mgr)
opener = build_opener(h)
page = opener.open(url)
io = StringIO(page.read())
print io.getvalue()
io.close()
```

I initially was using just `page.read()` but caused my console to just keep printing out the stream and wouldn't return to the code. I'm now trying to use StringIO to process this like a stream and print it out incrementally, but when I do this I get nothing and the process just holds. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I would highly recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I hear good things about the requests module:

https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#id9

Answer (score 4):

Please read Streaming Requests¶

https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#streaming-requests

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/stream/20', stream=True)

if r.encoding is None:
    r.encoding = 'utf-8'

for line in r.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True):
    if line:
        print(json.loads(line))
```